# Need wsdl corrections, null output from deserialization with Axis 1.3

Tags: c#, xml, wsdl, deserialization, axis

Having a though problem at work.
I need to integrate correctly a external Axis 1.3 webservice in c#. I'm aware of the null output problem and I spent last 2 days following several advices here and playing with namespaces and parameters in wsdl trying to make it deserialize correctly.
Servise is a simple method that uses a string as input and returns another string in output, so no complex elements.
This is wsdl provided from other developers (I replaced the original address with TEMP for privacy reason)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://TEMP.it:9080/FATCAKYC/axis/CallQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXml" 
                  xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" 
                  xmlns:impl="http://TEMP.it:9080/FATCAKYC/axis/CallQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXml" 
                  xmlns:intf="http://TEMP.it:9080/FATCAKYC/axis/CallQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXml" 
                  xmlns:tns1="http://integration.ws.it" 
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
                  xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.3
Built on Oct 05, 2005 (05:23:37 EDT)-->
  <wsdl:types>
    <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://integration.ws.it"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <element name="input" type="xsd:string"/>
    </schema>
    <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://TEMP.it:9080/FATCAKYC/axis/CallQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXml"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
      <element name="inputReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
    </schema>
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLRequest">

    <wsdl:part element="tns1:input" name="input">

    </wsdl:part>

  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLResponse">

    <wsdl:part element="intf:inputReturn" name="inputReturn">

    </wsdl:part>

  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXml">

    <wsdl:operation name="getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXML">

      <wsdl:input message="impl:getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLRequest" name="getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLRequest">

      </wsdl:input>

      <wsdl:output message="impl:getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLResponse" name="getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLResponse">

      </wsdl:output>

    </wsdl:operation>

  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="CallQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXmlSoapBinding" type="impl:WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXml">

    <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

    <wsdl:operation name="getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXML">

      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

      <wsdl:input name="getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLRequest">

        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

      </wsdl:input>

      <wsdl:output name="getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLResponse">

        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

      </wsdl:output>

    </wsdl:operation>

  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXmlService">

    <wsdl:port binding="impl:CallQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXmlSoapBinding" name="CallQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXml">

      <wsdlsoap:address location="http://TEMP.it:9080/FATCAKYC/axis/CallQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXml"/>

    </wsdl:port>

  </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

this is class generated automatically from visual studio

```
namespace BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto {


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://TEMP.it:9080/FATCAKYC/axis/CallQuestionarioFatcaComp" +
        "letoNoXml", ConfigurationName="CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXml")]
    public interface WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXml {

        // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the operation getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXML is neither RPC nor document wrapped.
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction="*")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
        BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLResponse getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXML(BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLRequest request);
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
    public partial class getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLRequest {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://integration.ws.it", Order=0)]
        public string input;

        public getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLRequest() {
        }

        public getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLRequest(string input) {
            this.input = input;
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
    public partial class getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLResponse {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://TEMP.it:9080/FATCAKYC/axis/CallQuestionarioFatcaComp" +
            "letoNoXml", Order=0)]
        public string inputReturn;

        public getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLResponse() {
        }

        public getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLResponse(string inputReturn) {
            this.inputReturn = inputReturn;
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    public interface WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXmlChannel : BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXml, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    public partial class WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXmlClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXml>, BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXml {

        public WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXmlClient() {
        }

        public WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXmlClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }

        public WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXmlClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXmlClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXmlClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLResponse BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXml.getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXML(BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLRequest request) {
            return base.Channel.getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXML(request);
        }

        public string getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXML(string input) {
            BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLRequest inValue = new BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLRequest();
            inValue.input = input;
            BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLResponse retVal = ((BizTier.Application.FATCAQuestionnaire.CallQuestionarioFatcaCompleto.WsIntegrationFatcaCompletoNoXml)(this)).getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXML(inValue);
            return retVal.inputReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

this is a input soap example

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:int="http://integration.ws.it">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <int:input> example input string </int:input>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

this is a output soap example

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <inputReturn xmlns="http://integration.ws.it">example string output
      </inputReturn>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What i need to change to make it work? i tried to force in output namespace"http://integration.ws.it" or remove the namespaceces from parameters but no luck.

Any other advices?

Answer (score 2):

solved by a peer

service reference is no good , this kind of services need web reference

the code generated has this line

```
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("getQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXMLReturn", Namespace="http://TEMP.it:9080/FATCAKYC/axis/CallQuestionarioFatcaCompletoNoXml")]
```

just replacing parametes and namespace with the ones found in output soap response I finally had output correctly deserialized

```
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("inputReturn", Namespace = "http://integration.ws.it")]
```

my hunch was right, but i was simply using the wrong referencing